How to modify Linux system call table in kernel version 6+?
I need to direct an external library making a system call to a function defined in my userspace application.

I cannot use LD_PRELOAD because I need static linking.

I cannot use ftrace/a Linux kernel module to intercept the call because this would require the function be in kernel space and that's not possible. It's C++ and quite a lot of code.


What about a kernel module modifying the sys call table to point to an address for the function? My application would locate the function at the same address.
Is it still possible to overwrite the sys call table in the latest linux kernels?
In the past you could locate the table with kallsyms_lookup_name and change the CR0 value to give permissions. However, I think Linux kernel 5 or 6 made changes to stop this. However, I don't fully understand how much the changes stopped this. I think they stopped exporting kallsyms_lookup_name, so maybe it's still possible, just more-difficult?
(I'm aware editing the table is frowned upon but this is not for customer usage, there are no security implications/it's a closed system).

I accepted some of the edits, but a couple of suggested bullet points weren't listable items.

You seem to ask this question one more time.

@3CxEZiVlQ I deleted the old question. It asked without writing a kernel module. Here I am proposing to write a kernel module. Completely different question.

Taking one step back from your XY problem is seccomp an option? brief intro it would allow you to trap the system call and run a bit of code of your own. Depends on you whether you want to do this by listening to a file descriptor (SECCOMP_RET_USER_NOTIF) or use ptrace (SECCOMP_RET_PTRACE)

One problem is that the system call table doesn't actually exist for x86 since kernel v6.9.

Even if you modified the system call table, you would need a handler function in kernel space for it to call. It would be up to that function to communicate with your handler in userspace.

A system call from one process cannot be directed to a userspace address in a different process.

@IanAbbott they removed the entire table? How do syscalls work now?

"How do syscalls work now?" For the architectures that have removed the system call table so far, it has been replaced by a switch statement.
